# Is there any way to bypass .htaccess PATH restriction (in URLs)?

Tags: apache, htaccess

We use `.htaccess`  to deny direct access to specific file `example.com/myfile.txt`, by using this configuration:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} myfile.txt
RewriteRule ^    - [F,L]
```

The intent is that if the url contains `myfile.txt`, we block the request.  However, what are extra protection steps? I think someone might access that file using backslashes (or any escape character) like:
`example.com/my\fi\le\.txt`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While what you've listed will work, `mod_rewrite` is not *really* an access control tool.  Apache provides you with tools specifically for denying access, which operate after the file names have been canonicalized (converted to the form that will be used to open files on disk).  Using something like this is the intended way to block access to myfile.txt:

```
<Files myfile.txt>
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

Your backslash example should make no difference -- the user will just get a 404 error, because a file named `my\fi\le\.txt` will not exist.  (Backslashes are a perfectly legal character in UNIX filename, and you can send them, although most browsers will convert them to forward slashes because Windows users.)

Comment: thanks! in backslashes i just meant any escape character (if there are any), that might bypass htaccess